# Word or phrase for "make someone see dreams"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a better way to say "make somebody see dreams", e.g. in the sentence

> Don't make me see dreams when I know they won't come to be true.

Answer (score 1):

A **cathexis** is [the investment of emotional significance in an activity, object, or idea.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cathexis)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "dream" in this context refers primarily to "hope":

> dream — something hoped for: something that somebody hopes, longs, or is ambitious for, usually something difficult to attain or far removed from present circumstances

This leads us to the word "hope" which can easily fit into your example:

> Don't make me see hope when I know these dreams won't come true.

An extremely common phrase for this is "false hope":

> Don't fill me with false hopes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> "*Don't lull me into (settling in) a [**fool's paradise**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fool%27s+paradise)*."

**Fool's paradise**: a state of enjoyment based on false beliefs or hopes; a state of illusory happiness.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about the sentence and its intimations. In this context, I like the idiom "pipe dream." Depending on your relationship with him/her, here's what I would say:

> I'm not gonna' fall for these pipe dreams!

Or (harsher):

> I'm not gonna' hold my breath over your petty pipe dreams!

The latter would certainly get the message across.

Answer (score 0):

how about *expect*?

e.g., don't make me expect anything when I know they won't come true

Answer (score 0):

"Don't make me see lucid dreams. "
Here lucid is a state when person knows he is dreaming and what he is seeing will not happen.